# XML XSD to AVRO avsc mapping in Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, avro

I am having an XML file and XSD file as input. The ideal goal is to serialize the XML data into AVRO based on avro schema (avsc) and deserialize back the same.

The XSD file is converted into POJO with xjc tool in java
The AVSC file is also converted into POJO with avro-tools.jar

The XML data is mapped to XSD POJO.

Can anyone suggest how this XSD POJO can be mapped into the AVSC POJO for avro serialization?

The XML data is very large and contains many nested element. Both the XSD and AVSC mapping is okay.

Comment: is anyone there to answer this challenge?

Comment: I have the same problem to solve too. I'm studying and making some tests with this project https://github.com/roycem90/xml-avro, do his work but I think some modifications should be done. It can be util for you?